# Actions of finite groups on exotic smooth manifolds of dimension >4

Tags: differential-topology, at.algebraic-topology, finite-groups, smooth-manifolds

Let $M_1^n$ and $M_2^n$, $n>4$ be two smooth compact manifolds that are homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic. Suppose that a finite group is $G$ acting faithfully on $M_1^n$ by diffeomorphisms. Is it true that $G$ admits as well a faithful action on $M_2^n$ by diffeomorphisms?

If no, what would be the a (relatively) simple example?

For example, can one differentiate exotic structures on $S^7$ this way?

Comment: there is absolutely no reason to expect for something like this to be true. Finding explicit counterexamples is quite a different story.   I don't know of any examples in dimensions  above 4 if you don't restrict the action in any way. For example I believe it's not  known if every exotic sphere admits a circle action.

Comment: @aglearner: Reinhard Schultz had a sequence of papers titled "Differentiable group actions on homotopy spheres" in 1980s, you should check them for such examples.  

Comment: you might also look at Weinberger's articles on propagating group actions, e.g. http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=910951


Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is no. But I don't know the reason. I take the fact that exotic spheres in dimension 7 do not admit orientation reversing diffeomorphisms (but the standard sphere does) as a clue to say that one shouldn't expect an affirmative answer to your question.

**EDIT**: I gave a wrong answer and I'm not sure if I can delete the post. I decided to change my answer by a comment and make it CW. My apologies to those who read this expecting to see a right answer...

Comment: The OP doesn't link the actions of $G$ on $M_1$ and $M_2$ in any way. so the action of $Z_2$ on an exotic sphere is not required to be orientation reversing. 

Comment: Mauricio, where can I read about the fact that exotic 7-spheres don't admit an orientation reversing diffeo?

Comment: In Milnor's original paper http://www.jstor.org/stable/1969983 he constructs some manifolds homeomorphic to the 7-sphere which do not admit orientation reversing diffeos (and so are exotic spheres)

Comment: In Milnor's original paper or these notes http://www.nd.edu/~lnicolae/MS.pdf  by Liviu Nicolaescu.

Comment: note that not every exotic sphere does not admit an orientation reversing diffeo. most don't but some do. oriented diffeomorphism classes of exotic spheres form a finite group under connected sum. the spheres that admit orientation reversing diffeomorphisms are exactly the elements of order 2 in that group.

Comment: This is a great answer and I'm disappointed by its low score and retraction. Although aglearner's question can be interpreted precisely, it is reasonable to interpret it loosely and this answer is certainly a prerequisite to any fancier questions. If aglearner really wanted the more difficult question, he should have indicated understanding of this step in the question and can certainly edit the question to do so. Also, this answer does address the final question of distinguishing exotic spheres....Also, I'm upvoting this answer so that the site stops bumping the question.